# Match string and remove associated CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

So I have a Javascript array of CSS selectors:

```
array is like the following: '.header', '#footer', '#nav', etc
```

I also have a div containing my site CSS as text (12,000 lines long):

```
<div id="all">
#nav
 {
   border: 1px solid;
   color: black;
 }
 #footer
 {
   display: block;
 }
 </div>
```

I need to take each selector from the array and for its match in $('#all'), remove everything from the start of the selector to it's end bracket.

i.e.

```
// for each from the array
$('#all').find($(this));
// removes everything from selector to its end bracket
```

Can anyone advise? It's to remove unused site CSS. I've been stuck for a while. Appreciated!

Comment: The HTML you posted is not valid.  Unless you are outputting CSS as the content?

Comment: `('.header', '#footer', '#nav')` This is not  an array.

Comment: You are trying to remove the text from the div? jQuery selectors are not going to magically match text!

Comment: Are you writing CSS code inside of a html div element? what do you want to do with that?

Comment: The CSS code is stored as text inside the DIV. The array contains the names of selectors I want to remove from the CSS (which is text inside the DIV). It's to remove unused site CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update:** Added **debug mode**, **input**, and **output**.

Okay, I guess you have a bunch of CSS and you wanna remove a few rules. Let me assume these:

1. Each row has only one selector.
2. Each row starts with that selector.
3. Each row has one complete rule. i.e., `selector {property: value;}`

If the third option is not succeeding, there are a lot of [**CSS compressors**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=css+compressor&aq=f&oq=css+compressor&aqs=chrome.0.57.3073&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=css%20compressor&cp=15&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=css+compressor+online&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=css+compressor+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&fp=1fc7e9b832ceaa6b&biw=1920&bih=979), and you can use them to make this CSS:

```css
#footer
{
  display: block;
}
```

Into:

```css
#footer { display: block; }
```

Now once you have this in a text file, you can do the manipulation using PHP or some good programming language. I **do not recommend** client side one. Say if you have PHP, and you have the set of rules here:

```css
#nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
#footer { display: block; }
```

And you have your array:

```
$remove = array('.header', '#footer', '#nav');
```

You can use something like this:

```
<pre><?php
$debug = false;
$rules[] = ".header { border: 1px solid; color: black; }";
$rules[] = "#nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }";
$rules[] = "#footer { display: block; }";
$rules[] = "#header { border: 1px solid; color: black; }";
$rules[] = ".nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }";
$rules[] = ".footer { display: block; }";
$remove = array('.header', '#footer', '#nav');
$final = array();
foreach ($rules as $rule)
{
    if ($debug) echo "Debug: ", var_dump(strpos($rule, " ")) . "\n";
    if ($debug) echo "Debug: ", var_dump(substr($rule, 0, strpos($rule, " "))) . "\n";
    if ($debug) echo "Debug: ", var_dump(in_array(substr($rule, 0, strpos($rule, " ")), $remove)) . "\n";
    if ($debug) echo "---\n";
    if ( !in_array(substr($rule, 0, strpos($rule, " ")), $remove) )
        $final[] = $rule;
}
echo implode("\n", $final);
?></pre>
```

The above script includes a debug. If you set `$debug` to true, you can see the different stuffs being checked.

The input given to this is:

```css
.header { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
#nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
#footer { display: block; }
#header { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
.nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
.footer { display: block; }
```

The output is:

```css
#header { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
.nav { border: 1px solid; color: black; }
.footer { display: block; }
```

#### Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ehd-z4j